# Automatic Recovery of MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have an application in *C language* which inserts the report data in MyISAM table by using *mysql_stmt_execute()* function.
Due to load on the table, it gets crashed.

For auto repair of crashed table, I have added following option in `/etc/my.cnf` file

```
myisam-recover-options=FORCE,BACKUP
```

When the table gets into a crashed state, then *mysql_stmt_execute()* function fails and I can't insert the reports. As I have specified recovery options, expected result should be, table gets repaired and application should work fine.

## QUESTIONS

- How to repair the table automatically when it gets crashed ?
- Why **myisam-recover-option** can't recover the table when query is executed ?

Answer (score 1):

[myisam_recover_options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_myisam-recover-options) is not a dynamic variable. [It is among the startup options for MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-start.html).

If you have set this option in `my.cnf`, mysqld must be restarted

Please restart mysqld with

```
# service mysql restart
```

or if you have Windows

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

You should try switching your table to InnoDB and make your table crash-safe.

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo for your answer. After adding option in my.cnf I have restarted mysqld service, but *mysql_stmt_execute()* still fails. I manually repair the table with *myisamchk* utility. Please suggest me the way which will automatically repair the table when it goes in crashed state.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to stick with MyISAM instead of Innodb?